# How to get original requestcode from onActivityResult which is call another onActivityresult in itself?

Tags: android, kotlin, startactivityforresult

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            data?.data?.let { cropImage(it) }
            if (requestCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                try {
                    val resultdata = CropImage.getActivityResult(data)
                    ...
                    if (requestCode == IMAGE1) {
                       ...
                    } else if (requestCode == IMAGE2) {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            ...
        }
    }
```

The CropImage method return another requestCode and override it so I can't use the function which is use IMAGE1, IMAGE2.
How can i use request==IMAGE1,2 Function?

Comment: could you post activity call code?

Comment: ```startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, IMAGE1) and startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, IMAGE2)```

Comment: ```CropImage.activity(uri).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
            .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE)
            .setMultiTouchEnabled(true)
            .start(this)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use CropImage library.
You can use it like following also.

```
Intent intent = CropImage.activity(uri)
                         .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)             
                         .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE)             
                         .setMultiTouchEnabled(true)
                         .getIntent(getActivity());

startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE1);
```

Comment: I didn't think that way.  You saved my day. Thanks you !